# What does examples.desktop do?

Tags: files, system

What's the point of the `examples.desktop` file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is a location launcher. A desktop shortcut to a location.

The contents looks something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Name=Examples
Name[es]=Ejemplos
Name[fi]=Esimerkkejä
Name[fr]=Exemples
Comment=Example content for Ubuntu
Comment[es]=Contenido del ejemplo para Ubuntu
Comment[fi]=Esimerkkisisältöjä Ubuntulle
Comment[fr]=Contenu d'exemple pour Ubuntu
URL=file:///usr/share/example-content/
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=example-content
```

It just opens nautilus at /usr/share/example-content/

The example content directory is a show case of open source and free culture.

You can read more about [example content here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/example-content).
You can [learn more about .desktop files here](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en).

Comment: It's fine to delete it.

Answer (score 11):

It shows up as a shortcut to a folder in the Files manager (circled in red).

I find it annoying as well. It's just an example, you can delete it. You can also delete it from `/etc/skel` to prevent it from appearing for newly created users too:

```
sudo rm /etc/skel/examples.desktop
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a shortcut to a folder called examples.It contains Ubuntu Free Culture Showcase and Case Studies.