# Why do we have .desktop files?

Tags: filesystem, files, .desktop, file-format

I wonder why do we have .desktop files, I downloaded a trivial .jpg picture from internet (yes, I'm a newbie, currently learning command line), and saw that when I list the file, I saw .desktop extension even if I move that file to the documents etc.

How necessary are they? What functionality do they constitute? How to remove them?

Comment: https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/

Comment: `.desktop` files are Progam Launchers

Comment: Burak, I'd be interested to see the output of `ls Desktop` and if possible a desktop screenshot! It would be nice to see if there is an issue and something odd downloaded.

Comment: What probably happened is actually that you created a `.desktop` format shortcut on your Desktop, to that picture's original URL online.

Comment: @Tim Here, I took a screenshot of what you might probably wanted(http://i58.tinypic.com/epg66x.png).  In the original form, instead of rabbit.jpg, its format was, <some-gibberish-words>.jpg.desktop, however, before asking the question I removed it unconsciously because I didn't know what was that :)

Comment: @Tim Btw, my Desktop is empty, the picture is in Documents

Comment: @underscore_d regarding the picture that I sent, I think you probably guessed correct. Sorry I just switched to Linux, those stuff are new to me :)

Comment: @Burak. Yes, I think that was a thing! Not to worry - as it was on the desktop it's unlikely to be important - if it was it will still be saved in `/usr` and if not then it doesn't matter - you've not uninstalled anything.

Comment: If you come from the Windows world, compare to a `.lnk`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.desktop` files are very important. When you search the Dash for programs, or click a program in the Launcher at the side, you are using a `.desktop` file.

In Ubuntu, most programs can be launched with a command from terminal - for example firefox can be opened with the command `firefox` in terminal, and Chrome is `google-chrome`.

A `.desktop` launcher does this for you. When you click, it runs the command - so you don't have to interact with the terminal at all.

This is a basic `.desktop` file. The `#` signs are comments that I've added.

```
[Desktop Entry]    # Tell the computer what file this is (a launcher)
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application  # Specifies what to do when clicked (there is also Link and Directory).
 Terminal=false    # Whether to open a terminal and run the command, or just run without
 Exec=firefox      # The command to run
 Name=Firefox      # A name to display
 Icon=/usr/share/icons/firefox.png  # Location of the icon
```

These files are clearly important - and you can create them yourself to run custom commands.

You can put one of these files (from `/usr/share/applications`) onto the "Desktop" and then use that to launch the program. It sounds like what you did was the following:

1. There is already a .desktop file, unrelated to the following download.
2. You download a file - and then list the files and see something like this:

   ```
   firefox.desktop
   trivial.jpg
   My Document.odt
   ```

   That `.desktop` file is unrelated to the download.
3. Moving the `.jpg` understandably does nothing - the files are unrelated. If you post a screenshot of your Desktop and also the output of the command `ls Desktop`, we can have a look and compare the two.

   Note that the name of the `.desktop` file when you look with the terminal can be completely different from the displayed name of the `.desktop` launcher. For example, Google Chrome extensions will show as their name, for example "Chrome Remote Desktop", but the file name will be `gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp.desktop`. This could be happening here - a weird saved name that doesn't seem to link to the launcher you would recognise.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: very nice =)....@Tim

Answer (score 2):

`.desktop` files have two functions:

1. They inform the desktop environment how the file is to be handled by the desktop environment with regard to menu placement, display, environmental variables, and similar. They are located in `/usr/share/applications/`.
2. They provide direct shortcuts on the desktop.

Hope this helped you out **:)**

Answer (score 0):

The main function is the direct shortcut

So if you want to have an application both in the menu and on your desktop, you’ll need to put the `.desktop` file

As @blade19899 commented `.desktop` files are Progam Launchers.

For  location of `.desktop` files refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files)

<sub>refer [here](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Desktop files are a FreeDesktop standard.
There are currently three types: `Application`, `Link`, and `Directory`.

> This specification defines 3 types of desktop entries: `Application` (type
> 1), `Link` (type 2) and `Directory` (type 3). To allow the addition of new
> types in the future, implementations should ignore desktop entries with an
> unknown type.

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

## Application-type desktop files

This is an example Application-type desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Calculator
Comment=Perform arithmetic, scientific or financial calculations
Keywords=calculation;arithmetic;scientific;financial;
Exec=gnome-calculator
Icon=gnome-calculator
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Calculator;
```

When you do a search for "calculator" in a menu,
the name matches, so it shows this result and icon.
When you click on it, it runs the `gnome-calculator` application.
There are more examples of this kind of desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/`.

## Directory-type desktop files

This is an example Directory-type desktop file
from `/usr/share/desktop-directories/Utility.directory`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Accessories
Comment=Desktop accessories
Icon=applications-utilities
Type=Directory
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-menus-3.0
```

This means that there will be an "Accessories" entry in a hierarchical menu,
and because e.g. the calculator example above
has `Utility` in the `Categories` field,
the calculator will show up as a sub-entry of "Accessories".
The FreeDesktop spec also mentions
that these can include localized names in other languages:

> Directory entry
>
> A directory entry is a file with a name ending in the ".directory" extension
> which conforms to the [desktop entry
> specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/Standards/desktop-entry-spec) with
> `Type=Directory`. It provides a localized name and an icon for a submenu.
> Directory entries are also known as ".directory files."

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/go01.html

for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Directory
Verson=1.0
Name=Electronics
Name[ca]=Electrònica
Name[cs]=Elektronika
Name[de]=Elektronik
Name[el]=Ηλεκτρονικά
Name[es]=Electrónica
Name[eu]=Elektronika
Name[fi]=Elektroniikka
Name[fr]=Electronique
Name[hu]=Elektronika
Name[it]=Elettronica
Name[ja]=電子工学
Name[nb_NO]=Elektronikk
Name[nl]=Electro
Name[pl]=Elektronika
Name[pt_BR]=Eletrônica
Name[pt_PT]=Eletrónica
Name[ro]=Electronică
Name[ru]=Электроника
Name[sv]=Elektronik
Name[tr]=Elektronik
Name[zh_CN]=电子
Name[zh_TW]=電子學
Icon=applications-electronics
```

(Hierarchical menus for listing applications
[aren't supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236131/how-to-get-the-hierarchical-menus-with-launchers-for-all-applications-in-ubunt)
by the GNOME 3 desktop anymore,
but other desktops like
[XFCE4](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin#screenshots),
[KDE Plasma](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff),
and [LXDE](http://lxmed.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) still have them.)

There are more examples here:

```
/usr/share/desktop-directories/
```

## Link-type desktop files

This is an example Link-type desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Examples
Comment=Example content for Ubuntu
URL=file:///usr/share/example-content/
Icon=folder
```

This is a simplified version of the desktop file
provided from the `example-content` package.
When you click this in a file manager,
it navigates to this directory:

```
/usr/share/example-content/
```

In this case the `URL` field is a [`file://` URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme),
but it could be any other kind of URL,
such as an `https://` URL:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AskUbuntu.com
Type=Link
URL=https://askubuntu.com/
Icon=text-html
```

or a `mailto:` URL:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Email someone
Type=Link
URL=mailto:example@ubuntu.com
```

or an `smb://` URL:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Samba share
Type=Link
URL=smb://username@server/my-samba-share
```

or a special file-manager URL like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Trash
Type=Link
Icon=user-trash-full
EmptyIcon=user-trash
URL=trash:///
```

or this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Recent documents
Type=Link
Icon=document-open-recent
URL=recent:///
```

Related:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373239/what-is-the-advantage-of-desktop-files-without-executable-bit-set
- [What does examples.desktop do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2484/what-does-examples-desktop-do)

Comment: How to extend a ,Desktop File of Type=Link to add subentries pointing to other links. Such a Desktop File is used in /loca;/share/templates to "Create new File" at custom location by right clicking

Comment: @pasmon79 Please ask a new question about this describing your specific use-case. Off-hand, it sounds like what you are asking would be better implemented as a file manager extension.